# show/hide click div, desired: one item displayed at a time

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I have set up a show/hide div with js and I am having a difficult time figuring out how to show one div at a time.  what is currently happening, is each div displays unless I click the original link again to close out the div.

http://www.littlestoneacademy.com

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try to understand the need. The need is to display a block and hide others on click of a link. Just use `document.getElementById` and set the `style.display` attribute to `none` for those you need to hide, and `block` for those you need to show.

Have a  javascript somewhat like this(Change according to your needs):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(divName1,divName2,divName3){
            var div1=document.getElementById(""+divName1);
            div1.style.display="block";
            var div2=document.getElementById(""+divName2);
            div2.style.display="none";
            var div3=document.getElementById(""+divName3);
            div3.style.display="none";
        }
   </script>
```

And html code:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="toggle('div1','div2','div3');">DIV 1</a><div id="div1" style="display:none">hello1</div><br/>
 <a href="#" onclick="toggle('div2','div1','div3');">DIV 2</a><div id="div2" style="display:none">hello2</div><br/>
 <a href="#" onclick="toggle('div3','div2','div1');">DIV 3</a><div id="div3" style="display:none">hello3</div><br/>
```

Comment: Its just a demo to give you an idea of what you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some styling as per the above example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function toggle(divName1,divName2,divName3){
         var div1=document.getElementById(""+divName1);
         div1.style.display="block";
         var div2=document.getElementById(""+divName2);
         div2.style.display="none";
         var div3=document.getElementById(""+divName3);
         div3.style.display="none";
     }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.divInfo { 
  display:none;
  border:1px solid red;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
</style>
```

And html code:

```
<table width=100%>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <a href="#" onclick="toggle('div1','div2','div3');">DIV 1</a><br/>
       <a href="#" onclick="toggle('div2','div1','div3');">DIV 2</a><br/>
       <a href="#" onclick="toggle('div3','div2','div1');">DIV 3</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="divInfo" id="div1">Div 1 Information</div>
      <div class="divInfo" id="div2">Div 2 Information</div>
      <div class="divInfo" id="div3">Div 3 Information</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would get rid of all inline event handlers that is obtrusive javascript and just use this line of code where all your javascript is in one place and place at bottom of document

evertime you click on a link it will associate that link with the div, hide all the children divs of panel then show the div with your link is associated with 
just remove all your inline javascript event handlers

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1]
var lis = ul.children
for (i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
lis[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var toggleId = "toggle"
    var id = event.target.id;
    var cutID = id.slice(7);
    toggleId = toggleId + cutID
    var panelChildren = panel.children
    for (j=0; j<panelChildren.length; j++) {
        panelChildren[j].style.display = "none"
    }
    document.getElementById(toggleId).style.display = "block"

}, false)
}
```

Comment: better to re declare the toggleId variable within each function